# Leaflet-draw : Create editable layers

Tags: angularjs, draw, leaflet, geojson, angular-leaflet-directive

My objective is to have a map to which I can add markers/polygons/... These elements will be saved into an Object for saving. The drawn elements can later be edited/deleted or added to.

I have successfully managed to create/edit/delete them, but when I init my map with the saved objects they can't be edited again.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4fq6m3dc/1/

My code :

```
leafletData.getMap().then(function (map) {

    var drawnItems = $scope.controls.edit.featureGroup;

    // Init the map with the saved elements
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedItems.length; i++) {
        layer = new L.GeoJSON($scope.savedItems[i].geoJSON);
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    }

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var layer = e.layer;
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

        $scope.savedItems.push({
            id: layer._leaflet_id,
            geoJSON: layer.toGeoJSON()
        });
    });

    map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
        var layers = e.layers;
        layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedItems.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.savedItems[i].id == layer._leaflet_id) {
                    $scope.savedItems[i].geoJSON = layer.toGeoJSON();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    map.on('draw:deleted', function (e) {
        var layers = e.layers;
        layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedItems.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.savedItems[i].id == layer._leaflet_id) {
                    $scope.savedItems.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code and it seems that I have fixed the bugs for you. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoapp">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/bower_components/leaflet.draw/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/bower_components/leaflet.draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css" />
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("demoapp", ["leaflet-directive"]);
        app.controller("ControlsDrawController", ["$scope", "leafletData", function($scope, leafletData) {
            $scope.savedItems = [{
                "id": 721,
                "geoJSON": {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-0.626220703125,
                            48.1367666796927
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "id": 724,
                "geoJSON": {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-0.274658203125,
                            49.13859653703879
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "id": 725,
                "geoJSON": {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-18.10546875,53.38332836757156],[-10.107421874999998,55.92458580482951],[-3.33984375,53.9560855309879],[-10.634765625,47.635783590864854],[-17.2265625,45.767522962149904],[-18.10546875,53.38332836757156]]]}} 
            }];
            var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedItems.length; i++) {
                L.geoJson($scope.savedItems[i].geoJSON, {
                    style: function(feature) {
                        return {
                            color: '#bada55'
                        };
                    },
                  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
                  }
                });
            }
            angular.extend($scope, {
                london: {
                    lat: 51.505,
                    lng: -0.09,
                    zoom: 4
                },
                controls: {
                    draw: {},
                    edit: {
                        featureGroup: drawnItems
                    }
                }
            });
            leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
                var drawnItems = $scope.controls.edit.featureGroup;
                // Init the map with the saved elements
                var printLayers = function () {
                    console.log("After: ");
                    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
                        console.log(layer);
                    });             
                };
                drawnItems.addTo(map);
                printLayers();
                map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
                    var layer = e.layer;
                    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON()));
                    $scope.savedItems.push({
                        id: layer._leaflet_id,
                        geoJSON: layer.toGeoJSON()
                    });
                });
                map.on('draw:edited', function(e) {
                    var layers = e.layers;
                    layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedItems.length; i++) {
                            if ($scope.savedItems[i].id == layer._leaflet_id) {
                                $scope.savedItems[i].geoJSON = layer.toGeoJSON();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                map.on('draw:deleted', function(e) {
                    var layers = e.layers;
                    layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedItems.length; i++) {
                            if ($scope.savedItems[i].id == layer._leaflet_id) {
                                $scope.savedItems.splice(i, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }]);
    </script>
    <style>
        input {
            width: 120px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ControlsDrawController">
    <leaflet center="london" controls="controls" width="100%" height="400"></leaflet>
    <h1>Draw control example</h1>
    <p>Draw a shape and a geoJSON data structure will be shown on the console.log.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fq6m3dc/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm correct saying that you changed my for () { drawnItems.addLayer(layer) } into drawnItems.addTo(map); ?